# Solving a statistics problem with both permutation and combination

Tags: permutations, combinations

[image: Question 17]

The question I'm having issues with is 17, as shown in the picture. I understand the difference between combinations and permutations, though I'm having trouble applying it to the question. This homework is not due per se, I just want to understand how to do it for an upcoming exam. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In the event whose probability you are trying to compute, $D_1$ and $D_2$ are not ready, $D_3$ is ready, and, of $D_4,$ $D_5,$ and $D_6$, exactly two are ready on one is not ready.  In the sample space, exactly three of $D_1,\ldots,D_6$ are ready and three are not ready.

Method 1 requires you to compute the number of outcomes in the event by placing one of the three symbols $N_1,$ $N_2,$ $N_3$ in slot one, a second of these in slot 2, and one of the symbols $Y_1,$ $Y_2,$ $Y_3$ in slot 3.  The three symbols not used may then be placed in any way whatsoever in slots 4, 5, and 6.  Try writing in each slot the number of ways each slot can be filled: you get $\underline{3}\,\underline{2}\,\underline{3}\,\underline{3}\,\underline{2}\,\underline{1}.$  To compute the number of outcomes in the sample space, the six symbols may be placed in any order, so there will be six choices for the first slot, five for the second, and so on: $\underline{6}\,\underline{5}\,\underline{4}\,\underline{3}\,\underline{2}\,\underline{1}.$

In Method 2, we only have two symbols, $N$ and $Y,$ each of which is to be repeated three times.  In computing the number of outcomes in the event, note that the first three slots are determined, so you only have to compute the number of ways of filling in the last three slots with the symbols that remain.  To compute the number of outcomes in the sample space, you will need to consider the number of ways of filling all six slots using the given symbols.  In both calculations, you will use combinations.  For example, in computing the size of the event, you have to choose which two of the last three slots are to contain $Y$s.  (One $Y$ is already allocated to the third slot.)  There are $\binom{3}{2}$ ways to do this.  In computing the size of the sample space, you have to choose which three of the six slots contain $Y$s.  There are $\binom{6}{3}$ ways to do this.